# Simplest command to print unique values of some column data with count of repeated values

Tags: text-processing, awk

A sample input data with 3 columns, 1st and 3rd column has values in duplicates, need to print them uniquely with their repetition count.

sort -u does help in some sense but unable to print occurrence of repeated values relating 1st and 3rd column.

```
Input :
```

```
A 3210 -06:00
A 5172 -06:00
A 3335 -07:00
A 3258 -05:00
B 3322 -05:00
B 5097 -05:00
C 3238 -06:00
C 5364 -05:00
C 3366 -06:00
C 3293 -06:00
```

Output :

```
A(2) -06:00 
A(1) -07:00
A(1) -05:00
B(2) -05:00
C(3) -06:00
C(1) -05:00
```

or

Output :

```
A 2 -06:00 
A 1 -07:00
A 1 -05:00
B 2 -05:00
C 3 -06:00
C 1 -05:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Given *Input* use `cut`, `sort`, `uniq` and `sed`:

   ```
   cut -d ' ' -f1,3 Input | 
   sort | uniq -c | 
   sed 's/^ *//;s/^\([0-9]*\) \([^ ]*\)/\2 \1/'
   ```
2. Using `datamash` and `sed`:

   ```
   datamash -t ' ' -g1,3 -s countunique 2 < Input | 
   sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 \3 \2/'
   ```

Output of either:

```
A 1 -05:00
A 2 -06:00
A 1 -07:00
B 2 -05:00
C 1 -05:00
C 3 -06:00
```

Comment: Nice, it is indeed handy , cut -d ' ' -f1,3 d.txt | sort | uniq -c                       
 I updated question to exclude those unnecessary (),

Answer (score 3):

Not precisely the format you want, but fits all other requirements:

`awk '{print $1" "$3}' <inFile> | sort | uniq -c`

In english, use awk to print only the first and third columns, then sort, then uniq with count.

Comment: An `awk` statement that uses arrays to do the counting for you _is_ handy.

Comment: I see it works  very well, nice one, I take my comments back ..

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{ count[$1,$3]++ } END { for (i in count) { split(i, field, SUBSEP); printf("%s(%d)%s%s\n", field[1], count[i], OFS, field[2]) } }' file
A(1) -07:00
B(2) -05:00
A(2) -06:00
A(1) -05:00
C(3) -06:00
C(1) -05:00
```

Note that the output may not be sorted.  Pass it through `sort` if needed.

The code stores the count for how many times the first and third fields of the input has occurred together as a pair, in the `count` array (with the first and third fields as the index). At the end, we loop over the indexes of the array, splitting them up into the original first and third fields (as `field[1]` and `field[2]` respectively) and output these together with the count in the wanted format.

---

In the alternative format:

If the input file uses a single space for field separator (otherwise use `awk '{ print $1,$3 }'` instead of the `cut`):

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 1,3 file | sort | uniq -c
   1 A -05:00
   2 A -06:00
   1 A -07:00
   2 B -05:00
   1 C -05:00
   3 C -06:00
```

To swap the two first columns:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 1,3 file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1, $3 }'
A 1 -05:00
A 2 -06:00
A 1 -07:00
B 2 -05:00
C 1 -05:00
C 3 -06:00
```

Comment: it does the job, but not quite handy, I would have to go back to find it out whenever needed, still looking ....

Comment: Nice, I end up with this myself,   awk '{count[$1" "$3]++;}END { for (key in count) print key,count[key]}'  file     .. but got some quite easy from here..